# Setting elements of an array as variables in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Say I have an array holding some variables such as `array = ["one", "two", "three"]`.
How would I assign `array[0]` to be a variable? I know this is probably the wrong way of implementing this, but I'm trying something like this:

```
var = 10   
instance_variable_set("@#{array[0]}", var)
```

I want to be able to call `puts @"#{array[0]}"` and it give me `10` as a result.

Edit: I am trying to set the array index (in this case "one") to be a new variable so that I can later call it in other methods. This way `set!` works for changing the variable later when the array not longer holds the same values. For example, if after setting `"one"` as a new variable whose value is `10`, if i get an array containing `["three", "two", "one"]` I want to be able to call `puts array[2]` and it give me `10`.

Comment: why not using `#instance_variable_get` ?

Comment: Can you show me an example of using #instance_variable_get to get the above results?

Comment: `puts instance_variable_get("@#{array[0]}")`

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to do? You say you "have an array holding some variables", but that's impossible. Arrays can only hold objects and variables aren't objects, therefore you cannot possibly "have an array holding some variables". What you have shown is an array holding some strings, not variables.

Comment: I want to CREATE a variable, as in if the index of the array holds a string "one" I want to create a new variable named "one" that I can call later.

Already answered by Steve below.

Comment: I'm just amazed at how far people will go out of their way to avoid using objects.

Comment: Instead of criticizing why not simply give suggestions? If someone is asking a question here clearly they do not understand how to achieve their goal. Otherwise nothing would have been asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
eval "@#{array[0]} = var"

p @one
=> 10
```

or

```
eval "p @#{array[0]}"
=> 10
```

as A Fader Darkly points out, eval is potentially dangerous, particularly if the value comes from user input.  What if the user enters, as a string, "`rm -rf /`" ?  You've now wiped out everything in your root folder.

Comment: I never actually know the name of the variable, so I cannot call it in my code. It would be in an array, so if "one" was at index 0, I'd need to call something like puts "@#{array[0]}"

Comment: Yeah you could do that.  I'm not clear why you want to but it works.

Comment: Except it would be `eval "puts @#{array[0]}"`

Comment: BINGO. Thanks Steve, that't exactly what I was looking for. You should add that to your answer.

Comment: Careful with eval. Never use it if the string may be coming from an untrusted source, as in a worst case it gives that source complete control over your computer. (Ruby can run shell commands...)

Comment: This is the most horrendous useless use of `eval` I have ever seen. What's wrong with `instance_variable_set`/`instance_variable_get`?

Comment: Nothing is wrong with using those as compared to eval, they both gave me the desired output. This way (eval) was just given first.

Answer (score 3):

Just set it like an array in most languages:

```
array[0] = var
```

Comment: This just stores the value into the array. I want the array element to be set to a NEW variable I can later call, that hold the value from var.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set instance variable you should probably call `@var = array[0]`